# IRC connection via SOCKS proxy for servers requiring SSL?

Tags: ssl, proxy, socks, irc

I use Sidestep on Mac OSX to make a proxy connection via SSH to an EC2 instance whenever I'm on public unsecured networks. In cases where the network has a more restrictive I can connect my IRC client to IRC networks like Freenode by configuring the client to use the local SOCKS proxy that Sidestep creates (which it does via `ssh -D`) but for servers requiring SSL this doesn't work.

Is there anything I can try for using the proxy when SSL is required or do I need to connect to / run a VPN?

Comment: As a followup, I removed Sidestep from the equation. I blocked all traffic to IRC ports on my router and confirmed that normal connections would not work.  Then I created a SOCKS proxy via SSH:

`ssh -CND 1080 me@thehost`

I confirmed that connecting to Freenode worked via the proxy. Connections to IRC servers requiring SSL still don't work. A paste of the SSH debug output showing my client attempting to connect to a couple of SSL-secured networks:  https://dpaste.de/1HpKm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the Textual IRC client. Upgrading to v3 resolved the problem. I can now connect to SSL secured IRC servers.